# what is different between "で" and "です" in this sentence?

Tags: copula

original sentence is

> ついに数日後、無事つながって私の頭の中が解明されました。『脳内イメージ』と題したそのページに映し出されたのは、脳の形。その中のほぼ９割が『遊』の字で、その周りを『悩』と『休』が取り囲んでいます。

what is different between

> 脳の形。その中のほぼ９割が『遊』の字**です**。その周りを『悩』と『休』が取り囲んでいます。

and

> 脳の形。その中のほぼ９割が『遊』の字**で**、その周りを『悩』と『休』が取り囲んでいます。

?

Comment: The で is not a particle (though you tagged this with `particle-で`)... You know the continuative form of the copula だ/です?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"です。" indicates that the sentence ends here.

"で、" , however, indicates that the sentence doesn't end here, but continues to the latter clause.

Comment: 主語はどれですか？「その中のほぼ９割」ですか？

Comment: Yes. I think so.